# Django form optional field still required error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have in my model the following fields:

```
field1 = models.CharField(max_length=63, null=True, blank=True)
field2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

and in my form, which extends `ModelForm`,  I haved added:

```
    field1 = forms.CharField(required=False)
    field2 = forms.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = TestForm
        fields = [
            'another_field', 'field1', 'field2'
        ]
```

But if I don't fill `field1` and `field2`, I get the following error:

```
TestForm with errors: <ul class="errorlist"><li>__all__<ul class="errorlist nonfield"><li>You must specify either a field1 or a field2</li></ul></li></ul>
```

AFAIK I woudn't even need to set `required=False` since the model has already set null and blank as true, so what am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was so worried about the `form` class, but it turns out someone on the project had already overridden the `clean` method on the model itself:

```
def clean(self) -> None:
        if not (self.field1 or self.field2):
            raise ValidationError("You must specify either a field1 or a field2")
        return super().clean()
```

By removing the lines above, the code now works!

Answer (score 0):

Try edit your form like this:

```
class My_Form(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = TestForm
    fields = ('another_field', 'field1' , 'field2')

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(My_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['field1'].required = False
    self.fields['field2'].required = False
```